# Internal DNS for non domain users

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, internal-dns, windows-dns

At the company I am at we have an Active Directory setup with an DNS server. All the computers that are part of the domain can resolve name from the DNS server with no problem.

The current issue is for computers that are not part of the domain. These computers can't resolve all the name correctly.

I tried putting the IP address for the DNS server into the routers static DNS, this worked for a few names, but there are still some names which wont resolve.

I did an nslookp and it seems that the computers are still going out to the ISP DNS and not ours.

Is there a way with out having to configure each machine to use our DNS when they are on our network?

Active Directory and DNS are running on Windows 2008

Answer (score 4):

What we did in this situation is we have all local computers (Domain and non-Domain) use our two A.D. DNS servers for DNS and that's it. We then have those DNS servers forward unknown requests to our ISP DNS.

A while ago, we had our DHCP server assigning our two DNS servers and then the ISP DNS as a tertiary. Like that, we would have random issues where one day someone could resolve a local host and other days they couldn't. So I removed the ISP DNS from the DHCP servers assignment. So now every device in the building uses the two internal servers and they have a forward lookup set to the ISP DNS. Works like a charm.

Comment: [This is why what you did didn't and won't work](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-client-all-proxies-must-provide-same-service.html), for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to assign the DNS suffix of your AD domain to the non-domain joined clients in order for them to submit fully qualified queries to your internal DNS server for internal domain joined hosts.